# Laying out components and managing state with animation stagger using React Native?

Tags: react-native

Im trying to solve a problem with managing state in my react native application. the effect Im trying to build is that the current items on screen stagger out of the screen while asynchronously bringing in the new items from offscreen when changing state, this is best represented with gif.

[image]

So basically when I change the the state for the active answerContainer, it should stagger the previous items out of the screen, while bringing the new items in.

**Code(Pseudo):**

```
this.state = {
   activeAnswerContainer: 1
}

... 

<AnswerContainer active={this.state.activeAnswerContainer === 1} ...
   <Answer />
   <Answer />
   <Answer />
   <Answer />
<AnswerContainer active={this.state.activeAnswerContainer === 2} ...
  <Answer />
  <Answer />
  <Answer />
  <Answer />
```

This is not an animation issue, as I already have the desired effect i need, my problem is dealing with the state, and how can I get the answerContainers to communicate with each other.